# Can i use docker-compose for scala projects?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, docker-compose

Has anyone here used docker-compose for scala projects (sbt)? Would like to understand ups and downs of using this with scala.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you to use docker-compose to bring up your project dependencies, once I used it to start MySQL and Hadoop (see [here](https://github.com/AlexITC/challenge-etl/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)) and then, run the project with sbt.

EDIT: I found this gist that tells gives you an example to integrate your sbt environment: https://gist.github.com/hlegius/ead3670eda810d653c7b2bcab4574cfe